# How to set title of bootstrap loading button?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button

I have the following code:

```
            var submit_button = $(t.find(":submit"));
            submit_button.button("loading");
```

I want the title of the button to be "Please wait...", but how can I achieve this?
If I set use "text" or "html" before the above call, the title is reset to "loading".

This was the solution - as provided below by Nimish Gupta:

```
var submit_button = $(t.find(":submit"));
submit_button.attr('data-loading-text', "Please wait...");
submit_button.button("loading");
```

Comment: had you tried setting `data-loading-text="Please wait..."` on button?

Comment: How do I set this on the button? I cannot modify the HTML code as it is auto-generated, so I need to do it from javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `data-loading-text="Loading..."` to your submit button along with js code

```
$("form").on("submit", function(){
    $(this).find(':submit').button("loading...");
})
```

Comment: Can you suggest code to add the data-loading-text from javascript as I cannot modify the html code? Thanks!

Comment: Add this line in your JS file. 

`$('form').find(':submit').attr('data-loading-text', 'Loading...')`

Above line should be written before

`$("form").on("submit", function(){`

    `$(this).find(':submit').button("loading...");`

`})`

Answer (score 0):

You can simple use ladda bootstrap button.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="form-submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg ladda-button" data-style="expand-right" data-size="l"><span class="ladda-label">Submit</span></a>

$(document).ready(function(){
Ladda.bind( 'input[type=submit]' );
});

$(function() {
    $('#form-submit').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var l = Ladda.create(this);
        l.start();
        $.post("your-url", 
            { data : data },
          function(response){
            console.log(response);
          }, "json")
        .always(function() { l.stop(); });
        return false;
    });
});
```

It will show a loader beside your button.

See more at : https://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/